# How can I get the last incremented value of data in PHP/SQL/AJAX

Tags: php, sql, database

What I did is that when I input a quantity of 5 and it's data for example is named "ABC-1000" the result is ABC-1001...ABC-1005, Now what I am aiming is when I record another set of data and will input any quantity it should start in ABC-1005, it's a little bit tricky for me. I tried doing query where I used subquery to get the max result but it still has some errors

Here is the picture of my dataTable.

[image]

Here is the picture of my form

[image]

Here is my code in HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label> Tools Name: </label>
     <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="tools_name" placeholder="Enter Tools Name" data- 
      live-search="true" onchange="ToolsChange(this)">
      <option value="" selected>Select Tools Name</option>
       <?php
         $result = mysqli_query($con, "CALL GetInformationUsingToolSpec()");
         $con->next_result();
         if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
         {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['tools_name'].'">' .  
            $row['tools_name'].'</option>';
            }
         }                                               
       ?>
      </select>
</div>
```

Here is my query inside my ajax call.

```
<?php 

include("../include/connect.php");

 
    if(isset($_POST['tools_id'])){
        
        $ID = $_POST['tools_id'];
        
        $query = "SELECT tools_masterlist.control_no, tools_masterlist.tools_id, tools_masterlist.tools_name, 
        tools_spec.model_num,tools_spec.model_num_val 
        FROM tools_spec 
        LEFT JOIN tools_masterlist 
        ON tools_spec.tools_id = tools_masterlist.tools_id WHERE tools_name = '$ID'";
        // $result=mysqli_query($con, "CALL 
        GetAjaxForToolsRegistration('$ID')");
        $con->next_result();
        $result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                echo $row['control_no'] . " " . $row['model_num'];
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why do you use `next_result()` before calling stored procedure? You are meant to use it after.

Comment: Hi @Dharman ohhh, I should rearrange it thanks!

Comment: @any_something simplest solution is to split the alpha characters part from the number and have the numeric part be saved in a different field of an integer type. Then you can short that numeric field and find the greatest each time you add new data using `ORDER BY <numeric_field> DESC`; get the number and increase it from where the last one was saved. Of course you concatate the 2 fields or format them before it needs to be displayed to the users.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of All, I want to put your intention to SQL Injections because your user can put anything in the input field. You are building your queries manually instead of using parameterized prepared statements.
You should know how to use **[htmlspecialchars()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp)** function.

So .......

```
$ID = $_POST['tools_id'];
```

should be converted to

```
$ID = htmlspecialchars($_POST['tools_id'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

You should call **next_result()** function after calling stored procedure.

Also, You should add a seperate column to store the numeric values instead of merging or concatenating with some else.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering :) . Yes I did separate and add a column for my numeric values. The only problem for me now is if the user has used and inputted a quantity, next the user adds a new record it should get the incremented value.

Comment: For that you should do like this quantity=quantity+user-input-quantity. It means the quantity value will be inserted by sum up of existing quantity and the quantity entered by user.
Kindly accept the answer if you are satisfying.

Comment: This is nonsense. `htmlspecialchars()` is not a tool for escaping input to SQL. It's intended for handling output to a browser. There is the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function for escaping data for SQL, but the correct approach is to use **prepared statements**.

Comment: You should increase your knowledge then to know what htmlspecialchars do. Good Luck.